# Excel: Is it possible to copy cells only if cells match in other columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If it's an EXACT duplicate, not just some answer that MAY suggest an answer then please provide the link in a comment.

Say, I have dates in column A of Sheet-1, and also dates in column A of Sheet-2. the problem is that Sheet-2 misses some dates.

Sheet-1

```
A1:2015-06-24 B1:34
A2:2015-06-23 B2:29
A3:2015-06-22 B3:56
A4:2015-06-21 B4:88
```

Sheet-2

```
A1:2015-06-23 B1:29
A2:2015-06-21 B2:88
```

I need to copy B(sheet-1) to sheet 2 only if a cell in A sheet-1 matches a cell in A sheet-2. So I just want to copy B2 and B4 from sheet-1 and place them in Sheet-2 as B1 and B2.

Is it possible?

I was trying to modify this formula:

```
=IF($A1=Sheet1!$A1, VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A1, Sheet1!$A1:$D1, 2),"")
```

Yet unsuccessfully, from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545581/excel-copying-cell-between-sheets-based-on-criteria)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi David. Can you tell me how my question is different from [this one on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545581/excel-copying-cell-between-sheets-based-on-criteria).

Comment: I would have made the same comment on that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH($A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))

should do the trick. It's a very basic use of INDEX/MATCH  (or VLOOKUP). Try to google one of those keywords you will find beginner tutorials

Comment: It sounds unbelievable, but it worked! Thank you